# jQuery Mobile - Back button not working in Web app

Tags: iphone, web-applications, jquery-mobile, iphone-web-app

I am new to Jquery mobile I have develop a website that work fine in Iphone safari browser  but when i make its home screen shortcut and run it as web app then if i move a step back its work fine but when i move two steps back its not working its refreshes the webpage.

e.g. I have three pages in my website A,B,C when I move from A to B and then going back to A its work fine same as when move from B to C and then going back to B its work fine. But when i move A to B and then C and then going back to B its work fine but when i move to A its refreshes the page rather than getting page from history. My back button code as below

```
 <a href="SearchMembers.aspx" data-rel="back" direction="reverse" id="btnBackMemberDetail"
            class="back-button" data-inline="true">Back</a>
```

Can anybody help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with multiple clicks breaking the javascript back button functionality. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092308/javascript-history-function-not-working-for-web-page-served-from-homescreen-on-i). Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change href="SearchMembers.aspx" in to href="/"

edit:

```
<a href="/" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" >Back</a>
```

I use this and this works fine for me.. I use jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js